# Rhino mocks of properties property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks

When I do these two lines after each other my code fails with `Previous method 'HttpContextBase.get_Request();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.` on the second line.

```
context.Expect(c => c.Request.UrlReferrer).Return(uri).Repeat.Any();
context.Expect(c => c.Request.HttpMethod).Return("POST").Repeat.Any();
```

However when I do just one of the rows the code runs fine.

Doing the following does not fix the problem.

```
context.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(request);
```

Anyone understands this strange behaviour?

Thanks,
Drutten

Edit: Entire code is:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var context = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var writer = new StringWriter();

        var form = new NameValueCollection();
        request.Expect(r => r.Form).Return(form);

        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/IntegrationTests");
        request.Expect(r => r.UrlReferrer).Return(uri).Repeat.Any();

        var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
        request.Expect(r => r.QueryString).Return(queryString);

        context.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(request).Repeat.Any();
        context.Expect(c => c.Request.UrlReferrer).Return(uri).Repeat.Any();
        context.Expect(c => c.Request.HttpMethod).Return("POST").Repeat.Any();
        context.Expect(c => c.Response).Return(response);
        context.Expect(c => c.Session).Return(session);
        context.Expect(c => c.Server).Return(server);
        context.Expect(c => c.Items).Return(new Dictionary<object, object>());

        response.Expect(c => c.Output).Return(writer);

        return context;
    }

    public static void MockControllerContext(this Controller controller)
    {
        var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), controller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem was probably related to the mix of

```
context.Expect(c => c.Request.UrlReferrer).Return(uri).Repeat.Any();
```

and

```
context.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(request).Repeat.Any();
```

Working code is:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/IntegrationTests");
request.Expect(r => r.UrlReferrer).Return(uri).Repeat.Any();

var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
request.Expect(r => r.QueryString).Return(queryString);

request.Expect(c => c.HttpMethod).Return("POST").Repeat.Any();

context.Expect(c => c.Request).Return(request).Repeat.Any();
```

I find it strange though that doing

```
context.Expect(c => c.Request.HttpMethod).Return("POST").Repeat.Any();
```

once worked, even when not setting return on Request.

Comment: By the way, why do you have some many expectations? In my experience, this is very hard to maintain. Usually you don't care whether a property had been read and how many times. You just stub them (using `Stub`) and if you really want to know if something had been called, use `AssertWasCalled` at the end. This is the beauty of AAA-Syntax.

Comment: @Stefan Thats true! I don't care how many times they were called, and should probably use stubs. I have added the Expects here just to get the correct return values but perhaps there is an easier ways using stubs?

Comment: Use `.Stub` instead of `.Expect`.